# Service probability for M/M/c queue for reneging where reneging time is a function of service time

Tags: queuing-theory, probability-theory

There is an M/M/1 (getting a result for M/M/c is ideal) queue with arrival rate  and service rate  and participants can renege.

However, the difference between normal reneging settings (constant time $\tau$) and this setting is that the participants know its service time ahead of time and the time to renege is a function of its service time (sampling from exponential). Let's say the function is a linear function of its service time $ w(\cdot) = a \cdot s$, where $ s \sim Exp(\mu)$ and $ a $ is a constant.

There is no balking.

What would be the expression for the steady-state probability that a participant receives service?